# Where is SimpleDelegator in Ruby 2.7?

Tags: ruby

I have been using the SimpleDelegator class for various things. But I noticed, Ruby 2.7 (ArchLinux x86_64) doesn't come with the SimpleDelegator class (no Delegator either).

My program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
class OutputDecorator < SimpleDelegator
    def puts(*args)
        STDOUT.write "Hello #{args.join}... It's Ruby #{RUBY_VERSION} #{RUBY_PLATFORM}\n"
    end
end

$stdout = OutputDecorator.new($stdout)
$stdout.puts('Sourav')
$stdout = $stdout.__getobj__
$stdout.puts('Sourav')
```

---

Running with:

- Ruby 2.4.6:

```
> ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin/ruby p.rb 
Hello Sourav... It's Ruby 2.4.6 x86_64-linux
Sourav
```

- Ruby 2.5.5:

```
> ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby p.rb 
Hello Sourav... It's Ruby 2.5.5 x86_64-linux
Sourav
```

- Ruby 2.6.3:

```
> ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby p.rb 
Hello Sourav... It's Ruby 2.6.3 x86_64-linux
Sourav
```

- Ruby 2.7.0:

```
> ruby p.rb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
p.rb:2:in `<main>': uninitialized constant SimpleDelegator (NameError)
```

---

Is there any new alternatives to SimpleDelegator in Ruby 2.7?

Comment: Maybe your Ruby was installed strangely because it works for me (Ruby 2.7.0p0). Can you reproduce this on another machine? Does it happen with an RVM or rbenv install? If it's specific to the distribution package you may need to take it up with the package maintainer.

Comment: The Ruby came from ArchLinux (`extra/ruby 2.7.0-1`). Probably it should be notified to the packager then...

Comment: NameError confirmed here with Ruby 2.7.0 installed with RVM, Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: Also, for me (ArchLinux x86_64 and ArchLinux ARM (raspberry pi 3B)), SimpleDelegator in irb is present. Only running a ruby script with /usr/bin/ruby seems to have this problem. Script works fine with RVM Ruby 2.7.0-preview1.

Comment: Are you using `2.7.0-preview1` or `2.7.0p0`? There may be a difference here.

Comment: I have Ruby 2.7 from Arch Linux's extra repo. Right after posting this post, I have installed Ruby 2.7.0-preview1 using RVM for test, but that doesn't have this issue.

Ruby 2.7.0 from ArchLinux x86_64 and ArchLinuxARM have this issue. But if I run irb (Ruby 2.7.0), SimpleDelegator works fine for some reason. Only SimpleDelegator in a ruby script fails to work.

Comment: Yet another reason to reinforce the idea that you [shouldn't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: `require 'delegate'` is missing? `SimpleDelegator` is not a core class but part of the standard library.

Comment: Thanks, `require 'delegate'` fixes the problem.

Comment: The bigger problem is that the documentation for SimpleDelegator and DelegateClass have vanished even from stdlib.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Delegator` and `SimpleDelegator` classes aren't core classes like `Array` or `Mutex`. They're part of the `delegate` standard library which needs to be loaded first: `require 'delegate'`.

It happened to work in older Ruby versions as they came with an older RubyGems version by default. RubyGems is automatically loaded since Ruby 1.9 and [until 3.1.0](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v3.1.0/History.txt#L15) that meant `delegate` was loaded indirectly. Updating RubyGems or running `ruby` with `--disable=gems` should cause the exact same issue with Ruby <= 2.6 too. `irb` also loads several standard libraries: `delegate` but also `timeout` and many more.

Programming languages with a similar mechanism like C++ also have this issue: instead of `load`/`require` there's `#include`, including a standard library header might include another one, then a newer version might not include the other header anymore and user code relying on the old behavior fails to compile.